# Can I make a shortcut contain two different programs on the taskbar?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

first post here. Couldn't find anything similar already posted.

On Windows 10, I have it set so that when I click the Google Chrome shortcut on my taskbar, it actually opens a batch file I made which later opens Chrome. This is what I want. The problem is, I end up with two Chrome icons showing in my taskbar since one is the batch shortcut and the other is the actual Chrome. I still want the batch file to open when I click the shortcut, but once Chrome opens it should appear under the same icon.

So here's what happens:
I click Chrome icon in taskbar>A batch file opens>Batch file launches Chrome and then closes>Chrome is open but its icon is now separate from the batch shortcut in taskbar

Hopefully I've made everything clear. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I don't believe this is possible without real development. The taskbar will show a jumplist for each distinct process with a window, running interactively on the desktop, aggregating multiple windows by processes path (without args), and .bats and .lnks and other tricks to run multiple process invocations by abstracting the target have no means to change that. I won't say its impossible to do, but I don't think you can do it with admin level tools like basic scripts. Sorry.

Comment: Shucks. Well thank you anyway for your time @FrankThomas! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

[Use the command `start`](https://www.wikihow.com/Run-a-Program-on-Command-Prompt). E.G.

```
start notepad
```

will run *notepad.exe* without showing the CMD prompt.

Comment: I think Peter wants the chrome windows to merge into the batch shortcut's jumplist on the taskbar, so that it doesn't display both the icon he clicks to start them, and the resulting windows separately. could be wrong. I do compliment you on the tip though. I did not know that.

Comment: Exactly so, Mr. Thomas. I'm not too familiar with the terminology of the taskbar GUI, so sorry if I was unclear at all. I appreciate both of you taking the time to help me @drmoishe-pippik

Comment: My terminology may be dated. When Vista came out, Jumplists and Areo Peek were used to describe taskbar tokens being merged together, and seen in miniature when hovered over by the mouse. I haven't heard newer terms for them, but then again, I haven't see the word 'jumplist' anywhere in quite some time. I'm getting old.

Comment: It's all good. Thanks for the info! Never knew that the entire time I've used Windows. First version of Windows for me was 98. Kind of know how you feel. Time just flies!